# TextField loses focus on each keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI textfield inside a Dialog.  On each keystroke, the whole dialog is re-rendered and focus is lost on the textField.  Each new character I add is persistent.

This is my dialog where the textfield and `onChange` are located.

```
const [action, setAction] = useState("");
function ActionDialog() {
    return (
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} fullWidth maxWidth="sm">
            <DialogTitle>Action ID: {open}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <TextField
                    value={action?.Comment}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setAction((prev) => {
                            return { ...prev, Comment: e.target.value };
                        });
                    }}
                    label="Comment"
                    variant="outlined"
                    size="small"
                />
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason your state variables are declared outside the `ActionDialog` component? Is that because the `ActionDialog` component is declared inside another parent component?
If that is the case, every time the state variable changes, it will create a new instance of the ActionDialog component. To make things simpler, make the state variables local to the component that is setting the state.